# Is there a dojo implementation of jSignature

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, dojo, svg

Is there a Dojo implementation/alternative to the jQuery [jSignature](https://github.com/brinley/jSignature) plug-in? Or alternatively: can jSignature be used with Dojo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jSignature relies on jQuery for (*a lot** of functionality. So, while you absolutely need jQuery for jSignature, nothing stops your from loading jQuery alongside Dojo.

Checkout jQuery NoConflict mode. jSignature has a special `jSignature.min.noconflict.js` build for that.